# ERROR: No matching distribution found for jaxlib==0.1.67

Tags: python, jax

I need `jaxlib==0.1.67` for a project I'm working on, but I can't
downgrade. At the moment I have `jaxlib==0.1.75` and my program keeps failing due to an error I can't find a solution to either. I compared all versions of the important packages to another machines versions where my programs runs with no problems and the only difference is the jaxlib version (it's still 0.1.67 on the machine where it runs). I suspect that jaxlib is the issue because the error I get when it's not 0.1.67 is the following:

```
    from haiku import data_structures
  File "/net/home/justen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/haiku/data_structures.py", line 17, in <module>
    from haiku._src.data_structures import to_immutable_dict
  File "/net/home/justen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/haiku/_src/data_structures.py", line 30, in <module>
    from haiku._src import utils
  File "/net/home/justen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/haiku/_src/utils.py", line 24, in <module>
    import jax
  File "/net/home/justen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/__init__.py", line 108, in <module>
    from .experimental.maps import soft_pmap
  File "/net/home/justen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/experimental/maps.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .. import numpy as jnp
  File "/net/home/justen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/numpy/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import fft
  File "/net/home/justen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/numpy/fft.py", line 17, in <module>
    from jax._src.numpy.fft import (
  File "/net/home/justen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/numpy/fft.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jax import lax
  File "/net/home/justen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/lax/__init__.py", line 334, in <module>
    from jax._src.lax.parallel import (
  File "/net/home/justen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/lax/parallel.py", line 36, in <module>
    from jax._src.numpy import lax_numpy
  File "/net/home/justen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/numpy/lax_numpy.py", line 51, in <module>
    from jax import ops
  File "/net/home/justen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/ops/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from jax._src.ops.scatter import (
  File "/net/home/justen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/ops/scatter.py", line 31, in <module>
    from typing import EllipsisType
ImportError: cannot import name 'EllipsisType' from 'typing' (/usr/lib/python3.10/typing.py)
```

haiku and typing are the same version on both machines so guess it must be jaxlib. On both machines I'm on `pip==20.0.2 and` in a python 3.9.9 virtualenv.

When I try to downgrade to `jaxlib==0.1.67` I get:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jaxlib==0.1.67 (from versions: 0.1.75, 0.1.76, 0.3.0, 0.3.2, 0.3.5, 0.3.7, 0.3.10, 0.3.14, 0.3.15)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for jaxlib==0.1.67
```

I even tried `pip install jaxlib==0.1.67 -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_releases.html` and it doesn't work.

Has anyone experienced the same problem or maybe has a clue of what could be the issue here to help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the path in the exception (`/usr/lib/python3.10`), it looks like you are using python 3.10. There are no python 3.10 wheels for jaxlib==0.1.67 ([see pypi](https://pypi.org/project/jaxlib/0.1.67/#files)). You will have to use python 3.6-3.9.

If you think you are using python 3.9, then here's a way to clear up confusion when installing packages. Use

```
python3.9 -m pip install
```

to install packages into your python 3.9 environment. Replace `python3.9` with whichever python interpreter you want to use.

Comment: God I'm stupid. I'm seeing I've used the peen-virtualenv completely wrong. I just set up the automatic activation and thought that's it, but somehow that didn't work and my virtualenv isn't working at all. I just checked `pip freeze` outside the virtualenv and its the same as inside. Seems like I have to read up again how it exactly works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by @jkr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73555919/2937831) is the correct answer for your question as written (how to install `jaxlib 0.1.67`), but I don't think it will fix the initial error you reported.

This looks like a Python 3.10 only bug that briefly existed in the JAX source code on October 5, 2021, but was [fixed](https://github.com/google/jax/pull/8104) and never actually made it into a jax release. If you're seeing this, I suspect it means you installed/imported JAX from unreleased source. Further, installing a different version of jaxlib will not fix this error, because the code is in `jax` itself. If you're using jaxlib 0.1.75, you might try installing jax v0.2.7 or v0.2.8, which were released around the same time, and shouldn't contain the problematic `EllipsisType` import.

Another potential issue: you reported using a Python 3.9.9 virtualenv, but your traceback indicates you're executing Python 3.10, so you probably need to check your executable paths to make sure you're executing what you think you are.

Comment: I think I screwed up with my `pyenv-virtualenv`. I'm not sure what it is exactly, maybe I'm not using the right commands, but everything is installed in the local python folder and not the virtualenv folder.

Comment: You probably ran `pip install`, and your path is set up so that `pip` points to the `pip` associated with the local Python. Try `which pip` and `which python` to see which you're using, and use `python -m pip install` to make sure you're installing things with the appropriate `python` executable.